# Monitoring raid status

Tags: centos, raid

I have installed MegaCLI on a centos 6 server and trying to monitor the raid status. When I run `megacli -PDList -Aall` this is the result:

```
[root@da435 MegaCli]# megacli -PDList -Aall
OSSpecificInitialize: Failed to load ./libsysfs.so.2.0.2 Please ensure that libsfs is present in the system.
The dependent library libsysfs.so.2.0.1 not available. Please contact LSI for distribution of the package
```

libsysfs library is installed:

```
[root@da435 MegaCli]# yum install libsysfs
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.tummy.com
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: mirror.cc.columbia.edu
 * updates: mirror.genesishosting.com
Package libsysfs-2.1.0-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `ldd megacli`?

Comment: ldd: ./megacli: No such file or directory

Comment: enter the full path to the `megacli` executable

Comment: Wow, man you saved me! it worked! I ran "./MegaCli64 -PDList -Aall | less" in "/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli" path.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the path to /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli first and then run the command with:

```
cd /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli
./MegaCli64 .
```